# Prototype for constructor does not match in class

Tags: c++

Hi there so I am very new to c++, and tried to make a simple program that takes in a few variables through the constructor, then some functions to change those values. However I am getting...

> [Error] prototype for 'User::User(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string)' does not match any in class 'User'.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "User.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {

// Simulates a current existing user
User u1("PizzaLover", "ilovepizza", "pizzaLover@gmail.com", "Tony", "Stark");

// Allows user to change their current username
u1.changeUsername();

// Allows user to change their current password
u1.changePassword();

// Allows user to change their current name
u1.changeName();

// Allows user to view their general account details
u1.printUserDetails();

return 0;
```

}

**User.h**

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
#include <string>
class User {

private:
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::string email;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;

public:
    User(string cUsername, string cPassword, string cEmail, string cFirstName, string cLastName);
    void printUserDetails(); // this allows the user to view their account details
    void changeUsername(); // this allows the user to change their username
    void changePassword(); // this allows the user to change their password
    void changeEmail(); // this allows the user to change their email
    void changeName(); // this allows the user to change their name
    };
```

**User.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "User.h"
using namespace std;
User::User(string cUsername, string cPassword, string cEmail, string cFirstName, string cLastName) {

username = cUsername;
password = cPassword;
email = cEmail;
firstName = cFirstName;
lastName = cLastName;   
}

cout << endl;
cout << "- - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
cout << "Username:\t" << username << endl;
cout << "Password:\t" << password << endl;
cout << "Email:\t" << email << endl;
cout << "Name:\t" << firstName << " " << lastName << endl; 
cout << "- - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
}

void User::changeUsername() {

string newUserName;

cout << endl;
cout << "Your current username is: " << username << endl;
cout << "Please input your new desired username: ";
cin >> newUserName;

if(username != newUserName) {

    username = newUserName;
    cout << "Your username has been successfully changed." << endl;
    cout << "Your new username is now: " << username << endl;
}

else {
    cout << "Your name is already set to that, next time try a new name." << 
endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use the constructor body to initialize members. Use the initialization list.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` in User.h?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes it has #ifndef USER_H, #define USER_H, #include <string>

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AJOA2ettRFAnm872) (after fixing includes and `string` vs `std::string`) please provide a [mcve]

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a82fa6ea8a30472)

Comment: I don't see any `#include` lines above. So this is not testable as is. Can you make sure the above represents exactly your problem (I should be able to copy and past the code above into files and do `g++ User.cpp`). If I have to make assumptions then I may be solving the wrong problem.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Change:

```
User(string cUsername, string cPassword, string cEmail, string cFirstName, string cLastName);

User::User(string cUsername, string cPassword, string cEmail, string cFirstName, string cLastName) {

username = cUsername;
password = cPassword;
email = cEmail;
firstName = cFirstName;
lastName = cLastName;   
}
```

To:

```
User(std::string cUsername, std::string cPassword, std::string cEmail, std::string cFirstName, std::string cLastName);

User::User(std::string cUsername, std::string cPassword, std::string cEmail, std::string cFirstName, std::string cLastName) {
   username  = cUsername;
   password  = cPassword;
   email     = cEmail;
   firstName = cFirstName;
   lastName  = cLastName;   
}
```

Comment: this would not explain the error OP reports, or OP reports the wrong fragment of the full error message

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Please explain what the cause of the problem is or how this solution fixes it.

Comment: @Jucky Dettinger thank you that resolved that error. However now the compiler gives this error now. main.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `User::User(std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string)' 
And also to each of the functions

Comment: @Surge That's why we're requiring a [mcve] here. Do so next time asking please.

Comment: @Surge Now you have to define that function or else you'll keep getting that error. BTW if people want to downvote my answer for giving you the right answer, I could care less.